# Why am I seeing 'yes' and 'no' in URLs crawled by Xenu?

Tags: urls, links

This may not be a WordPress thing at all, but I've never seen it before and it's happening to a WordPress site we're completing. I use [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) for checking sites for broken links, images etc. When I run it over our dev site I see loads of 404s for what are valid URLs, but with /yes and /no appended to them. i.e.

```
http://mysite/2014/04/my-fascinating-post/yes
http://mysite/2014/04/my-fascinating-post/no
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before?!

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: Well, do you _have_ these links in site anywhere?..

Comment: What happens if you try to load one of those URLs manually-- aka, paste it into a browser address bar?

Comment: Good questions both - I don't believe I have those URLs (they don't appear in the HTML source of the pages, for example) and they give 404s

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem - we're using the [Zemanta Related Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-posts-by-zemanta/) and somehow that was adding references to missing thumbnail images with src="yes" and src="no". Regenerating the missing thumbnail images got rid of this problem.